# docker run mysql just during one command

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I am trying to install phpmyadmin into docker containers.
I am doing something like that :

1. Installing the MySQL-server and the phpmyadmin dependencies.
2. In one command:

   1. Start MySQL-server.
   2. Install phpmyadmin.
   3. Stop MySQL-server.

This Dockerfile works perfectly on my computer but it is failing on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/olive007/ubuntu-mysql/builds/)

Is anyone who how to execute MySQL command during the docker building process ?

```
RUN apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
                    mysql-server-5.7 \
                    apache2 \
                    php7.0 \
                    php7.0-zip \
                    php7.0-bz2 \
                    php7.0-gd \
                    libapache2-mod-php7.0

# Fix MySQL home error
RUN usermod -d /var/lib/mysql mysql

RUN service mysql start && \
    apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends phpmyadmin && \
    service mysql stop
```

Comment: There is already `phpmyadmin` image available in docker hub, why create new one? Also why are you starting and stoping mysql in same run command!

Comment: @hasMobi-AndroidApps looks at line 14: apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends **phpmyadmin**

Comment: @leninhasda We have to start MySQL because phpmyadmin set a database during its installation

Comment: then why do you stop it?